# convert MOV to mp4 using transcode

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, transcode

I want to convert a MOV from my Casio cam to mp4 using transcode. Why transcode? Because I also want to deshake the video in the same step.

When I use

`ffmpeg -i in.MOV out.mp4`

it works. When using

`transcode -J stabilize -i in.MOV`

or

`transcode -J transform -i in.MOV -y ffmpeg -F mpeg4 -o out.mp4`

I get hundreds of these errors:

```
[ffmpeg_audio] Error: avcodec_open2 failed
[adpcm_ima_wav @ 0x1f7f180] Only 4-bit ADPCM IMA WAV files are supported
```

This looks to me as if transcode uses ffmpeg internally.

I could use ffmpeg to make it mp4 first and then use transcode to stabilize the video, but then it would be re-encoded twice which I would like to avoid.

This is what mplayer says about my MOV file:

```
MPlayer2 2.0-701-gd4c5b7f-2ubuntu2 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Cannot open file '/home/koem/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /home/koem/.mplayer/input.conf.
Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.

Playing 1-original.MOV.
Detected file format: QuickTime / MOV (libavformat)
[lavf] stream 0: video (h264), -vid 0
[lavf] stream 1: audio (adpcm_ima_wav), -aid 0, -alang eng
Clip info:
 major_brand: qt  
 minor_version: 537921536
 compatible_brands: qt  caqv
 creation_time: 2017-01-02 23:31:38
Load subtitles in .
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[vdpau] Error when calling vdp_device_create_x11: 1
[ass] auto-open
Selected video codec: H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 [libavcodec]
Selected audio codec: ADPCM IMA WAV [libavcodec]
AUDIO: 44100 Hz, 2 ch, s16le, 352.8 kbit/25.00% (ratio: 44100->176400)
AO: [pulse] 44100Hz 2ch s16le (2 bytes per sample)
Starting playback...
VIDEO:  1920x1080  29.970 fps  15940.0 kbps (1992.5 kB/s)
VO: [xv] 1920x1080 => 1920x1080 Planar YV12 
Colorspace details not fully supported by selected vo.
A:   1.1 V:   1.1 A-V: -0.000 ct:  0.000   0/  0 16%  8%  1.6% 0 0 

Exiting... (Quit)
```

How can I make it work with transcode without using ffmpeg first?

Answer (score 3):

FFmpeg has a [deshake](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#deshake) as well as a [stabilization](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vidstabdetect-1) filter. Get a new [binary](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) if yours doesn't.

To continue with your existing binaries, run

```
ffmpeg -i in.MOV -vcodec copy out.mp4
```

This will skip video re-encoding.

Comment: ok great! this did it: `ffmpeg -i in.MOV -vf vidstabdetect /tmp/x.MOV`  and then `ffmpeg -i in.MOV -vf vidstabtransform out.mp4`. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried your answer on Ubuntu 17.04 and it works.